# May a station transmit an automatic response to me on reception of my command?

Tags: united-kingdom, automation

Specifically, on a prearranged amateur band frequency, I wish to send a message. Upon recognising the message, the receiver would transmit an automatic response. I have a (UK) "Foundation" licence.

The receiver would be connected to a home automation system and the meaning of the message might be "turn on the lights". The response might mean "the lights have been turned on".

The message (and response) might take the form of DTMF sequences as this is probably the easiest to implement.

I'm not sure it presents a problem for licensing, except that I believe the responder would have a duty to transmit a callsign. So the question has become threefold:

- Can an automated responder possess its own callsign?
- Otherwise, may it use mine?
- May I hold an entire conversation like this in DTMF?

If not internationally covered, I'm interested in details specific to the UK.

EDIT: I have found a way by which the automated responder can respond in voice. As such. I have the option of broadcasting its (my) callsign, so that concern has gone away. Another thing I discovered by sitting the Foundation course is that one mustn't obscure the meaning of the transmission (eg by encryption). Arguably, since no-one else would know the meaning of my outgoing DTMF, the meaning of the message is obscured.

Anyway, the core question still remains: may I set up a station which responds autonomously to my incoming transmission?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know the UK regulations, but I would start by looking into the regulations around telecommand and telemetry - as well as automatic stations.

Comment: dunno about UK, but in the US, the automatic station can use your call if you set it up and you are responsible for its operation.  There are a few special rules for automatic stations and I think they are prohibited on some specific bands.